# azure log analytics stature streaming metric

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

successfully configured data-bricks cluster with Azure log analytics and i could see the following tables and respective log messages in log analytics but i'm not sure how to create a reports of out as i know KQL.

Can you please help to write sample query to get the following metrics by using the tables.

---

1. SparkListenerEvent_CL
2. SparkLoggingEvent_CL
3. SparkMetrics_CL
4. how many messages processed per sec?
5. no of inputs message and output message for sec?
6. Messages Latency ?
7. input vs out put message rate
8. no. of message processing rate per sec
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++

Answer (score 0):

Azure Databricks is a fast, powerful Apache Spark based analytics service that makes it easy to rapidly develop and deploy big data analytics and artificial intelligence solutions.

Connecting Azure Databricks with Log Analytics allows monitoring and tracing each layer within Spark workloads, including the performance and resource usage on the host as well as Spark metrices.

When you enable diagnostic setting for databricks, it will create 3 tables SparkMetrics, SparkLoggingEvent and SparkListenerEvent for logging spark related events.

#### Spark metrics

Spark metrics are automatically collected into the  SparkMetric_CL  Log Analytics custom log. We can use simple KQL query to work on them as shown below.

```
SparkMetric_CL
| where name_s contains "executor.cpuTime"
| extend sname = split(name_s, ".")
| extend executor=strcat(sname[0], ".", sname[1])
| project TimeGenerated, cpuTime=count_d / 100000
```

#### Structured Streaming metrics

Streaming job metrics are automatically collected into the  SparkListenerEvent_CL  Log Analytics custom log. Similar to the one mentioned above we can use simple KQL query to work on them as shown in the example below.

```
SparkListenerEvent_CL
| where Event_s contains "queryprogressevent"
| extend sname=strcat(progress_name_s,"-","triggerexecution")
| summarize percentile(progress_duration_Ms_triggerExecution_d, 90) by bin (TimeGenerated, 1m), sname
| order by TimeGenerated asc null last
```

#### Spark logs

Spark logs are available in the Databricks UI and can be delivered to a storage account. However, Log Analytics is a much more convenient log store since it indexes the logs at high scale and supports a powerful query language. Spark logs are automatically collected into the **SparkLoggingEvent_CL** Log Analytics custom log. Following are the example of simple KQL query.

```
SparkLoggingEvent_CL 
| project Message
| limit 50
```

There are also some prebuilt query names for retrieving Spark metrics in this [Access prebuilt queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/databricks-monitoring/databricks-observability#access-prebuilt-queries) section of the Microsoft document it will help you solve the remaining problems. When you open log analytics workspace and go to logs, it will open a query dialog. There you can search this prebuild queries.

I would suggest to read these [Stream processing with Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/data/stream-processing-databricks)
and [Use Kusto queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorial?pivots=azuredataexplorer) documents for more information.

Comment: --thank you for spending time and writing back the response. As I am pretty new to KQL and also I am not sure how to extract stream related details as I cloud not see any fields which are related to the below KPI. So would you please write some sample quires related to below.                                                                                           **Stage Latency Per Stage (Stage Duration)---
Stage Throughput Per Stage ---
Streaming Errors Per Stream ---
Streaming Latency Per Stream  --
Streaming Throughput Input Rows/Sec ---
Streaming Throughput Processed Rows/Sec **